# How do I set hours javascript date to larger than 23 and retrive them with the .getHours() function?

Tags: javascript, datetime

How do I set the hours of my javascript date object to a value larger than 23

When I look at the API 
[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)
the dates objects hours function seems to only accept values between 0 and 23,

Is there a way to push in larger values and retrive them by the .getHours() function properly?

```
var moreHours = new Date();
moreHours.setHours(25);
moreHours.getHours()
```

The code will return 1 instead of 25, does the Date API allow us to overwrite this by some official way?

Comment: What clock are you following that has `25` as hours?

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder 
I have a reusable component I want to behave "properly" some times, but if a parameter is set then I want it to return the time in hours even if larger than 23 hours..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , In some sense you are right about this falling into an XY problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to recompute the values.

#### Logic

1. Create base date
2. Create a backup copy
3. Add hours to date
4. While recomputing, `24 * difference in days` plus `dateObj.getHours()`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/bukxth7y/).

```js
function getHours(date, backUpDate) {
  var h = 0;
  if (date.toLocaleString() !== backUpDate) {
    var _bdate = new Date(backUpDate);
    _bdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var noOfDays = parseInt((+date - +_bdate) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    h = (noOfDays * 24);
  }
  h += date.getHours();
  return h;
}

function main() {
  var hr1 = 30;
  var hr2 = 100;
  var d1 = new Date();
  var d2 = new Date();
  d1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  d2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  var b1 = d1.toLocaleString();
  var b2 = d2.toLocaleString();
  d1.setHours(hr1);
  d2.setHours(hr2);

  console.log(getHours(d1, b1));
  console.log(getHours(d2, b2));
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to push in larger values and retrive them by the
>   .getHours() function properly?

No, as per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-hours-minutes-second-and-milliseconds)

> HourFromTime(t)   = floor(t / msPerHour) modulo HoursPerDay

and

> HoursPerDay   = 24

So, **NO**. It is not possible.

> The code will return 1 instead of 25, does the Date API allow us to
>   overwrite this by some official way?

It obviously doesn't make sense to have a clock for more than 24 hours.

But if you really want to do then set you need to implement your own date object since otherwise you will need to change a lot of methods in `Date.prototype` which can mess up some other funcitonality which wants to use the `Date` object in a right way.

Answer (score 1):

Days have only 24 hours in them, numbered 0 to 23 in the `Date` object. If you set a higher value, the `Date` object will automatically roll the date over to the next day. E.g.:

```
var dt = new Date(2016, 2, 10, 12); // March 10th, 2016 at noon
dt.setHours(25);
console.log(dt.toISOString());      // 2016-03-11T01:00:00.000Z
```

```js
var dt = new Date(2016, 2, 10, 12); // March 10th, 2016 at noon
dt.setHours(25);
console.log(dt.toISOString());      // 2016-03-11T01:00:00.000Z
```

Note how it ended up on the 11th at 1 a.m.

You can't change this behavior.

Comment: 1.0m score and just finetuning answers from 2016, respect 

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative. You can subtract the old date from the new date to get the expected value as this cannot be done by using gethours

Comment: The code sample is given in the  answer marked correct above